# Lattice structure-Lattice coefficients-Sign positive or negative?

Tags: filters, digital-filters, hardware-implementation, hardware

This is the question

$$ H(z) = \frac{1}{2 + 1.4z^{-1} + 1.8z^{-2}} $$

[image: Lattice structure]

My professor has told that we don't need to take those 2 values as negative and instead we can take them as positives(with the same arrow direction). Is he right? What should I do? I am seeing contradicting information on internet vs my professor(My professor doesn't check our final exam paper though)

Comment: "we don't need to take them  ..." for what? where? to what end?

Comment: he just told that and nth more than that. so no idea man.

Comment: Do you know how to get the lattice coefficients from the transfer function?

Comment: @Ryan yes for sure i know that

Answer (score 1):

The reflection coefficients for the system are 1, 0.368, and 0.9.

Based on the recursive difference equations for a lattice filter

$f_{m-1}[n]= f_{m}[n] - K_{m} \times g_{m-1}[n-1]$
$g_{m}[n] = K_{m} \times f_{m-1}[n] + g_{m-1}[n-1]$

That negative is important but should go on the other crossover as shown in this picture.

[image]

> http://www.expertsmind.com/learning/lattice-structure-assignment-help-7342873913.aspx

Bottom line. The negative in that picture should be on the other crossover and you should not “take it as a positive.” Your professor may know something that I don’t about it not mattering in the end, but you will always be right if you keep the negative in your calculations.

EDIT: I changed the picture because the first one I picked was confusing. You can ignore the ladder structure at the bottom since this is an all-pole filter.

Comment: "That negative is important but should go on the other crossover as shown in this picture."

I see the same picture as in question.

Comment: It is not the same picture as the question. Look closer at the signal flow graph and where the negative is.

Comment: Both have negative sign in upward arrow, that is what I see. Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: I found another picture of a block diagram. Can you see it now? It may help to look at the difference equation and try to draw it out yourself.

Comment: . both have negative sign in upward arrow https://imgur.com/a/qQjm8rG